# How to inform client of current state of execution

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I wish to have a progress bar on the client-side built using AngularJS. This progress bar will inform the end-user of the current state of execution of a query on the server.

The server, in this case, is ExpressJS.

So, using AngularJS I will make a request to the server such as:

```
$http.post('/data/aPath')
    .success(function (result){
        //Update the progress here.
    });
```

What I wish to know is how can I send responses without ending them so that AngularJS can receive them as shown above and I can update the progress bar? That is, on the Node.js side,

```
app.post('/data/aPath', function (request, response){
    //What should I do here to update the client on the
    //current execution state
    //Something on the lines of
    //response.write("finished fetching user details, moving on to
    //updating records"
});
```

so that the client can then update the progress bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, to be honest, but I believe one way to approach this would be like this:

On your client-side, modify your `$http.post` function

```
function getStatusFromProcessing() {
    $http.post('/data/aPath').success(function (result){
        // Pseudocode:
        if(result.status is something) { // ex: (result >= 20)
            // update progressbar with new value
        }
        if(result.status is somethingElse) { // ex: (result >= 40)
            // update progressbar with new value
        }
        
        // All updating of progressbar done for now
        if(result.status !== 100) { // Progress is not done
            return getStatusFromProcessing(); // run the function again
        } else {
            return; // All done, move on
        }
    });
}
```

Now, the server side:

```
app.post('/data/aPath', function (request, response){
    // You need some kind of function/service, which returns 
    // the current state of the processing.

    var currentStatus = getStatusFromRunningProcess(); 
    // getStatusFromRunningProcess() should return a value between (0 - 100)

    return response.json({ status: currentStatus});
});
```

A few notes:

- Code is not tested (obviously)
- Should you choose to do something like this, I think the processing time should be somewhat substantial in time
- Maybe add a small timeout in your client code inside `if(result.status !== 100)` of a couple of (hundred) milliseconds to avoid spamming the *http request*. But that is fine-tuning :)

**Update, alternative solution using sockets**

If you don't want to make several requests to the server from the client, you can switch it around; the server sends a message to the client when the process is updated. This requires more likely less bandwidth and requests done to the server. This method is possible using *sockets*.

When using sockets, the [socket.io](http://socket.io/) framework is very popular. There are also lots of tutorials online.

In short:

- The server sends a message when the status of the processing is updated
- The client receives this information and updates the progress bar

Here is a [SO post regarding sockets and a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183998/how-to-connect-formidable-file-upload-to-socket-io-in-node-js). This is about *file uploads* though, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Ah. Your solution goes for approaching the progress bar status through the client side. I think I may use this if I can't find a server side solution. I wanted to avoid this because this makes multiple calls to server - I was hoping to make just one single call.

Comment: Yes, this solution requires multiple calls to the server. But it's  kind of impossible to avoid it =/ Somehow the status of the processing needs to be sent to the client. Another way, which is almost the same, is using sockets. That way you can send _messages_ from the server to the client. Sockets is long polling, so instead of having to call the server for updated information, you call the client from the server when the information is updated. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am going with sockets for now, though I will still be on the lookout for a better alternative.